# Почему не получается передать в обобщенный метод коллекцию типов, реализующих интерфейс, без установки ограничений на <T>

Tags: c#

Опыт программирования небольшой, помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться.
  Имеется интерфейс IPinHelper с методом PinFavoriteItem:

```
 public interface IPinHelper
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Ставит\снимает флаг "Избранный" элементу, сохраняет в настройки и перемещает вверх в коллекции
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">Тип элемента, который нужно припинить\отпинить, должен реализовать интерфейс IPinnable</typeparam>
    /// <typeparam name="TSettings">Тип настроек, с которыми нужно взаимодействовать, должен реализовать интерфейс IPinnedItems</typeparam>
    /// <param name="pinned_item">Элемент, который нужно припинить\отпинить</param>
    /// <param name="pinnable_items">Коллекция элементов, в которой нужно найти pinned_item элемент и поставить\снять флаг "Избранный"</param>
    void PinFavoriteItem<T, TSettings>(IPinnable pinned_item, IList<T> pinnable_items)
        where T : IPinnable
        where TSettings : class, IPinnedItems, new();
```

Вызов метода выглядит так:

```
 SetChanelFavoriteCommand = new SyncCommand<ChannelItemViewModel>(
            execute: chanel =>
            {
                UtilFactory.Instance.PinHelper.PinFavoriteItem<ChannelItemViewModel, ChannelsSettings>(chanel, Channels);
            });
```

ChannelItemViewModel - реализует интерфейс IPinnable

```
ChannelItemViewModel : BindableBase, IPinnable
```

а Channels - это:

```
ObservableCollection<ChannelItemViewModel> Channels
```

Не могу понять, почему не получается в параметрах установить коллекцию  `IList<IPinnable> pinnable_items` и убрать ограничение `where T : IPinnable`

```
void PinFavoriteItem<TSettings>(IPinnable pinned_item, IList<IPinnable> pinnable_items)            
        where TSettings : class, IPinnedItems, new();
```

Если я убираю ограничение и принимаю в параметр  `PinFavoriteItem(IList <IPinnable> )`
тогда не получается отправить коллекцию Channels `ObservableCollection<ChannelItemViewModel> Channels`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробовал принимать в параметр вместо `IList<IPinnable> ObservableCollection<IPinnable>` - все равно выдает ошибку приведения

Comment: вы же понимаете, что `ObservableCollection<IPinnable>` и `ObservableCollection<ChannelItemViewModel>` - это разные типы?

Comment: но ChannelItemViewModel же реализует IPinnable интерфейс

Comment: и что с того? Вы создали коллекцию для жирафов, и пытаетесь сказать, что эта коллекция для всех животных, что не является правдой, хотя жираф является животным.

Comment: почитайте про ковариантность и контрвариантность, может оно станет немного понятней.

Comment: Спасибо большое, что обратили внимание на мой вопрос, почитаю в таком случае...

Comment: тогда не очень понятно, как первый параметр в `PinFavoriteItem(IPinnable pinned_item)` может без ошибки принять channel(который `ChannelItemViewModel`), получается тут тоже самое, только с единицей информации вместо коллекции

Comment: Если взять хомяка и сказать, что он является животным - это корректно. Если взять клетку хомяка и сказать, что она для любого животного - это не корректно, так как бегемот тоже животное, но в клетку хомяка не влезет.